# Zeta function for curves in a manifold

Tags: arithmetic-topology, mg.metric-geometry, nt.number-theory, zeta-functions

#### Motivation

In the analogy between prime numbers and knots, the prime number is thought sometimes as the circle of length $l([p]) = \text{log}\,p$. This is so you can express the zeta function as 
$$ \zeta(s) = \sum_{D\ge0} e^{-l(D)s}$$

where the sum goes over effective divisors on $\text{Spec}\,\mathbb Z$ and length is extended there by additivity. Similarly, you can do it to rewrite Dedekind zeta function for other number fields.

#### Question

I wonder, **what is the right analogue of above formula** for a manifold with metric? Perhaps:

1. integration over all closed curves of the expression $e^{-l(D)s}$
2. summation over positive sums of classes of closed geodesics.

I think I've heard something about definition 2, but I suspect if the two above are defined correctly they will be the same. Is it possible to formalize this definition? Do different formalizations lead to the same zeta-function?

#### Updates

Yes, I think this should be related to Laplacians, Selberg trace formula and dynamical system zetas. What I said I've heard about definition 2 was probably the [Selberg zeta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_zeta_function), but I can't say it clearly, hence questions.

Comment: That sum looks a little bit like the McShane identity. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McShane%27s_identity

Comment: Not exactly, because the sum there is alternating. But it should be in this terminology $L_T(-1, \chi) = 1/2$ where $L$ is a suitable analogue of $L$-function for torus $T$ and a "character" $\chi$.

Comment: Does not really qualify for an answer, but perhaps the zeta-function for a Laplacian could be a good strating point? see e.g. here: http://books.google.com/books?id=gzJ6Vn0y7XQC&pg=PA144

Comment:  I think that zeta-function of a Laplacian should be related, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There's been a lot of work since Smale's idea of a dynamical zeta function for general flows (in particular geodesic flows).  A good starting point would be this 12 year old [review by Baladi](http://www.dma.ens.fr/~baladi/etds.ps). There is a large and more recent literature but I'm no expert, although this [other review by Liverani and Tsuji](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~liverani/Lavori/live0602.pdf) is probably not far from current knowledge.

There's also a whole branch of physics around those ideas, indeed related to the spectrum of the Laplacian and applications to quantum physics and statistical physics. [This nice physics book](http://chaosbook.org/) is a good start (in particular if you read the quote of Smale at page 3 of [this chapter](http://chaosbook.org/chapters/det.pdf), and then remark 19.2 at the very end of that chapter you'll get a quick sense of the stuff you've aked for).

Answer (score 2):

In a  slightly  different spirit,
but still carrying the analogy between closed curves and primes,
The Selberg trace formula relates a sum over the   lengths of
closed geodesics on a hyperbolic surface (compact or no)
to the spectrum of the Laplacian on said surface. 
Googling `Selberg trace wiki' will get you started here.

This formula has provided inspiration for Guillemin
and collaborators working in spectral geometry and micro-local
analysis.